# How to call invoke operation on domain service?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have silverlight business application. I added an invoke method to my AuthenticationService class that returns bool.

How do I call this and get the result from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707370(v=vs.91).aspx#Y1804

```
 var authCtx = new AuthenticationContext();
            authCtx.HasAccess1(io => {
                HasAccess1 = io.Value;
            }, null);
```